# Stuck with FlutterViewController.mm(462)] Could not launch engine with configuration

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, cross-platform

I am struggling to integrate the [Particle Device Setup Library](https://docs.particle.io/reference/ios/#device-setup-library) into a Flutter application. I have followed Flutter.io's example on how to integrate [Platform Channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) to bridge the Flutter application with native code. 
I have successfully opened the connection to the native Particle SDK and can configure a Photon. However, I cannot progress from here.

My intension is to redirect the user to a new page when successfully returning from the setup phase. If the setup phase fails the user should be able to start over (this functionality is not implemented yet).

In the class `ParticleSetupState` from within `initState()` I call `initiateParticleSetup();`.

I have initialized the following variables:

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel("unique_placeholder/particle-setup");
String _particleSetup = "awaiting";
String particleSetup = "placeholder";
```

The `initParticleSetup()` is structured in the following way:

```
Future<Null> initiateParticleSetup() async {  
            String route = "";
            Map<String, dynamic> arguments = {};
            arguments.putIfAbsent("route", () => route);
            print("route: $route");
            try {
              tempRoute = await platform.invokeMethod("initParticleSetup", arguments);
              // Must be a valid route or a parameter passed back from the result of
              // the setup phase making the application navigate to the next screen 
              // upon successful configuration.
              particleSetup = route;
            } catch (e) {
              particleSetup = "Error: $e"; // Should allow the users to configure the setup again.
            }

            if(!mounted) { return; }
            print("After finishing native code: $route"); // This line is causing the the VERBOSE-2 errors messages
          }
```

`AppDelegate` contains the following code:

```
   override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
        ) -> Bool {

        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController;
        let initParticleSetupChannel = FlutterMethodChannel.init(name: "unique_placeholder/particle-setup", binaryMessenger: controller);

        initParticleSetupChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in                
            if ("initParticleSetup" == call.method) {
                print("Just entered initParticleSetup")
                let argument = call.arguments as? NSDictionary
                var route = argument!["route"] as? String
                print("initial route: \(route)")
                self.initParticleSetup(result: result)
                route = "/proceed"
                print("route is overwritten: \(route)")
                result(route)

                print("leaving initParticleSetup")
            } else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
            }
        });

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    private func initParticleSetup(result: FlutterResult) {
        if let setupController = ParticleSetupMainController(setupOnly: true) {
            print("before self.window? stuff")
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(setupController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("after self.window? stuff")
        }
    }
```

When I finish the setup phase and return to Flutter code the following errors are printed in the console:

```
[VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(157)] Could not prepare to run the isolate 
[VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(116)] Engine not prepare and launch isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterViewController.mm(462)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

I am suspecting it is caused by the print() after the `try {} catch {}` method as "After finishing native code: $route" is never printed to the console. I can't figure out how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Can you share the output of `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Actually, in particular, could you share what channel/tag you are on for Flutter?

Comment: flutter doctor -v return the following: `Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-DK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.2.4)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!`

Comment: Are you doing your changes in the `Runner.xcodeproj` or your own Xcode project?

Comment: I am doing the changes in Runner.xcodeproject (opened from the Flutter project)